# What is the value of Vbb in the circuit given below?

Tags: circuit-analysis

An NPN transistor is shown the figure. Here we can see that only Vcc is given. I am wondering what the value of Vbb is, as I want to calculate the base current.

[image]

Comment: For a silicon transistor Vbe is nominally taken as 0.6 - 0.7V leaving you about 8.4V across the 800k but that would have come up with **a minimal amount of research** about NPN transistors.

Comment: You need to define terms you use, like Vbb.  This is apparently the base voltage in this case, but you really should fix this sloppiness.  What's with the fingers(?) shadow and the totally uncropped picture?  This sort of stuff says *"Eh, you lot don't matter"* to the volunteers you are asking a favor of.  Not smart. -1 for the disrespect.

Comment: @Olin I am really sorry if it seemed to be an act of disrespect. I just love and respect this site equal to or more than I do my teachers

Answer (score 1):

A bipolar transistor looks like a diode between B and E to the rest of the circuit.  For a ordinary silicon transistor, that is usually 550 to 750 mV or so, depending on current and temperature.

700 mV is usually a good enough value for analyzing most circuits, and certainly is in this case.  That means Rb has 8.3 V across it.  The current won't be all that different whether it has 8.25 or 8.4 V across it.

Comment: I have learnt that a transistor is normally operated with two power supplies. One across collector emitter (i.e Vcc) and other across Base emitter ( i.e Vbb). In this circuit Vbb is not mentioned so how can I calculate Base current?